# How to Avoid "Press spacebar to activate" in JAWS

Tags: javascript, screen-readers

I'm new to JAWS, I have written javascript code on pressing spacebar for a particular button, But on JAWS on tabbing each button it says **"press spacebar to activate"** for all the buttons.

I need to avoid saying that message. any idea

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is called a tutor message and can't (and shouldn't!) be removed by a web developer. Beginners hear this on each and every button in Windows, not only on the web.
So if you want to suppress this on your system, just turn off tutor messages (in the JAWS main menu, it's the first set of radio buttons in the Basics dialog).